# Warning /usr/lib/php/20210902/memcached cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory igbinary_serialize_serialize in Unknown on line 0

Tags: debian

if someone can help me for fix please

Debian 11

error when restart php8.1-fpm (error apear only when restarting service)

NOTICE: PHP message: PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library 'memcached' (tried: /usr/lib/php/20210902/memcached (/usr/lib/php/20210902/memcached:  cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory), /usr/lib/php/20210902/memcached.so: undefined symbol: igbinary_serialize)) in Unknown on line 0

> 

`php -v` return no warning/error

> apt install php8.1-igbinary
> Reading package lists... Done
> Building dependency tree... Done
> Reading state information... Done
> php8.1-igbinary is already the newest version (3.2.14-1+0~20230618.45+debian11~1.gbpcc1dca).
> 0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
> apt install php8.1-msgpack
> Reading package lists... Done
> Building dependency tree... Done
> Reading state information... Done
> php8.1-msgpack is already the newest version (1:2.2.0~rc2-3+0~20230620.38+debian11~1.gbp2bc756).
> 0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.

info.php return memcached enabled:
[image]

file is here:

```
ls -la /usr/lib/php/20210902/memcached.so
```

-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 125136 Jun 22 06:58 /usr/lib/php/20210902/memcached.so

Thanks very much